# Different Derivative's output with ComplexExpand

Tags: functions, complex, calculus-and-analysis

Consider this expression

```
f = Abs[ x + I ]
```

with this assumption

```
$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals]
```

Now there is something strange: why are the following derivatives different?

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[D[f, x]]]
D[ComplexExpand[f, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}], x]
(* (I + x)/Sqrt[(I + x)^2] *)
(* x/Sqrt[1 + x^2] *)
```

Note that the argument of the derivative is the same

```
FullSimplify[
 ComplexExpand[f, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] == f]
(* True *)
```

Comment: Run `Trace` on your `In[3]` inputs to see the order of computations.

Comment: @corey979  
So does ComplexExpand work in a wrong way with `Abs'[I+x]`?